# How I can access the elements returned for by KeyCharacterMap.getEvents function from Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to use the `JKeyCharacterMap.getEvents` function from Delphi to get the KeyCode from a Char.

So I'm using this code.

```
uses
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge;

var
  s : string;
  PlatformKey : Word;
  FKeyCharacterMap: JKeyCharacterMap;
  events  : TJavaObjectArray<JKeyEvent>;
  event   : JKeyEvent;
  chars: TJavaArray<Char>;
  l : integer;
begin
  FKeyCharacterMap := TJKeyCharacterMap.JavaClass.load(TJKeyCharacterMap.JavaClass.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);

  chars    := TJavaArray<Char>.Create(1);
  chars[0] := 'A';
  events   := FKeyCharacterMap.getEvents(chars);

  l := events.Length; //this returns 4
  if l>0 then
  begin
   event := events[0]; // Segmentation fault (11)
   PlatformKey := event.getKeyCode;
  end;

end;
```

but unfortunately as soon I try to access to some element of the array returned by the `JKeyCharacterMap.getEvents` function I got a `Segmentation fault (11)` exception.

So the question is, How I can access the elements returned by the  KeyCharacterMap.getEvents function from Delphi?

**UPDATE**

I debugged using a break point where the exception is raised and the App fails on this function `Androidapi.JNIBridge.TJNIResolver.GetObjectArrayElement` because the `JNIEnvRes` variable is nil

```
class function TJNIResolver.GetObjectArrayElement(AArray: JNIObjectArray; Index: JNISize): JNIObject;
begin
  GetJNIEnv;
  //JNIEnvRes is nil
  Result := JNIEnvRes^.GetObjectArrayElement(JNIEnvRes, AArray, Index);
end;
```

The `GetJNIEnv` function is failing assigning a value to the `JNIEnvRes` variable.

```
class function TJNIResolver.GetJNIEnv: PJNIEnv;
begin
  if JNIEnvRes = nil then
    PJavaVM(System.JavaMachine)^.AttachCurrentThread(System.JavaMachine, @JNIEnvRes, nil);
  Result := JNIEnvRes;
end;
```

But I don't know what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Put a break point on the first line of the failing function and step through the code to determine which line raises the error. It might be that the array you're accessing doesn't exist, at least at the time you are examining it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, `GetJNIEnv` is working well. Though it seems that returns nil, it is Delphi's debugger showing a wrong value for `JNIEnvRes`, as you can see that `Result` is not nil:

```
class function TJNIResolver.GetJNIEnv: PJNIEnv;
begin
  if JNIEnvRes = nil then
    PJavaVM(System.JavaMachine)^.AttachCurrentThread(System.JavaMachine, @JNIEnvRes, nil);
  Result := JNIEnvRes; 
  // debugger shows JNIEnvRes as nil and Result as not nil
end;
```

In fact, `GetObjectArrayElement` is returning the expected object, but it is the subsequent `WrapJNIReturn` the one that fails, due to `FClassID` being `nil`. `FClassID` is needed to create a wrapper object with the proper class.

```
WrapJNIReturn(AObject, FClassID, FBaseType.Handle, Result);
```

---

You have two ways to solve this:

#### 1. Obtaining a raw item and wrapping it in an object with the correct type

```
events := FKeyCharacterMap.getEvents(chars);

l := events.Length; //this returns 4
if l>0 then
begin
  //event := events[0]; // Fails!
  event := TJKeyEvent.Wrap(events.GetRawItem(0)); // works
  PlatformKey := event.getKeyCode;
end;
```

#### 2. Wrapping the array within one with the correct ClassID

```
events := TJavaObjectArray<JKeyEvent>.Wrap(FKeyCharacterMap.getEvents(chars));

l := events.Length; //this returns 4
if l>0 then
begin
  event := events[0]; // now working well
  PlatformKey := event.getKeyCode;
end;
```